# How do I block direct access to Nexus except for localhost?

Tags: reverse-proxy, nexus

I have a Nexus standalone install (2.7.0) that is fronted with an IHS reverse proxy. I want to block direct access to the Nexus instance so that users are forced to use the IHS front end.

How do I configure this in Nexus?

Answer (score 1):

By default Nexus listens on all network interfaces.

You can change this by editing $NEXUS_HOME/conf/nexus.properties and changing this line:

```
application-host=0.0.0.0
```

Set it to an address on a restricted subnet, such as the loopback address:

```
application-host=127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You would configure that in your reverse proxy simply not allowing e.g. port 8081 through.